# Open a view controller from a local notification in ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift4, ios11

I have an ios 11 app that uses local push notifications for remainders at a given time.  The local notifications work and when swiped they open up the main view of my app. My app's main view is a uitableviewcontroller.  The reminders are rows in the table view.

If you click on a reminder it open's a new view controller by self.presentview... The new view pops up over the table view. I am not using storyboards or xib files and doing it programmatically.

How do I pass the reminder id to the push notification and back to the app and then have that reminder id open the second view controller?  The second view controller has more details about the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answer of anuraj.  set the required details in `userInfo`

Then handle the navigation using the following method (in `appDelegate.swift` )

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

      print("didReceiveRemoteNotificationfetchCompletionHandler \(userInfo)")
      let id = userInfo["reminderID"] as! String
      /// HANDLE NAVIGATION HERE
      if let tableVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? yourTableViewControllerClass {
        let reminderDetailsVC = yourReminderDetailsVC()
        reminderDetailsVC.reminderID = id
        tableVC.present(reminderDetailsVC, animated: true)
      }


    }
```

Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I can't get didRecieveRemoteNotification to be called? I wonder why

Comment: The local notification is on the app lock screen and I open it but it misses that function

Comment: Then, you have missed something in configuring local notifications. I have not implemented local notifications. Just make sure that you have properly configured local notifications

Answer (score -1):

While scheduling local notification you can set the required details in `userInfo`

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = "Alert!"
    notification.alertAction = "open"
    notification.hasAction = true
    notification.userInfo = ["reminderID": "222" ]
```

You will get the userInfo in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        print("didReceiveRemoteNotificationfetchCompletionHandler \(userInfo)")

/// HANDLE NAVIGATION HERE 



    }
```