# Local notification not calling didReceiveRemoteNotifications in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swift4, ios11

I have the following appDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    ...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])
    {
        print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
}
```

I am using ios11 and swift 4.1 but the notification gets fired off correctly. But when I tap it I can't grab it in the app. Why?  I am using xcode 9.4.1. Thanks.

The app is in the background and when the notification is tapped the app opens up.

Comment: what's the state of app? background/closed/opened?

Comment: What is local push notification ? is it push notification or local notification ?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: If you just want to get local notification response, try it userNotificationCenter.
I think your code is for remote notification  (didReceive**Remote**Notification)

Comment: I want to grab the local notification when someone taps on it. How is that done? I have these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626479/open-a-view-controller-from-a-local-push-notification-in-ios-11/51665847?noredirect=1#comment90295635_51665847

Comment: @cdub it wont call didReceiveRemoteNotification method because you are not getting notification from remote server so you should use UNUserNotificationCenter for this. Please refer below answer.

Comment: Yeah I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @cdub You should use usernotificatioCenter

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // do code here to show notification alert in for-ground mode 
}




func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    //your notification handling code here 
    }
```

Comment: Does this go in appDelegate too? Just curious

Comment: yes of-course you have to place it in appdelegate

Comment: its working now thanks

Comment: My Pleasure @cdub please do upvote too

Comment: How do you grab the userInfo from the response? I guess that is a separate question

Comment: notification.request.content.userInfo ==== like this in willPresent delegate and response.notification.request.content.userInfo ==== like this in didReceive